# Symfony command question input doesn't finishes

Tags: symfony, symfony-console

I'm trying to create a symfony console command. I'm using symfony Question to ask for input. But in console input doesn't finishes by "enter" press

That's code I have in my command execute method:

```
$io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
$passQ = new Question('<question>Please enter the password for the user</question>', 'password');
$password_raw = $io->askQuestion($passQ);
```

And that's what I have in my console:

```
 Please enter the password for the user [password]:
> lololo


q
nckvndk\
^C
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my computer is pretty slow :)
The only thing I had to do is wait a little bit more